# What does 'roaming aggressiveness' do on my WiFi adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

My Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 adapter has a setting under the Advanced tab called 'Roaming Aggressiveness'. What does this do and is there any benefit to putting this on either Lowest or Highest?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Roaming Aggressiveness - what does this do?

> This setting alters the signal strength threshold at which the WiFi
> adapter starts scanning for another candidate AP. Find this setting
> under the advanced adapter settings. The default value is Medium.
> Depending on the environment, one option may work better than the
> other. You may try other values to see which works best for your
> environment. We recommend you to revert back to the default (Medium)
> if you don't see an improvement with other values.
>
> - Lowest: The WiFi adapter will trigger roaming scan for another candidate AP when the signal strength with the current AP is very low.
> - Medium-Low
> - Medium: Recommended value.
> - Medium-High
> - Highest: The WiFi adapter will trigger roaming scan for another candidate AP when the signal strength with the current AP is still
>   good.

Source: [Wi-Fi Roaming Aggressiveness Setting](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005546/wireless/legacy-intel-wireless-products.html)

---

#### So there any benefit to putting this on either Lowest or Highest?

As per above you need to experiment to find out what is the best setting for your setup.

Answer (score 2):

Roaming Aggressiveness is relevant if and only if you have more than one wireless access point.

If you do have more than one wireless access point, then increasing roaming aggressiveness makes your computer more likely to switch between them.

This is good if your PC is getting 'stuck' on one of them, when the other would be better. e.g. if you move between rooms, and your PC keeps using the access point in the other room.

This is bad if your PC starts thrashing between two roughly equally good access points, or if you'd prefer your PC to stick to a slightly weaker access point for whatever reason - remembering that your PC can only decide based on the strength of the wireless signal - if one access point has better upstream data or cheaper upstream data, that's not visible to your PC.

Higher aggressiveness may also drain your battery slightly faster, if that's an issue.

At least, that's what theory says should happen, and for you, it might.

For me, in practice, whatever I set aggressiveness to, my laptop sticks to the currently selected wireless access point like a limpet. I have had some luck by turning *down* signal strength - at least for me, this makes the 'other' wireless point unreachable without noticeable effect on the connection to the 'good' wireless point.

Good luck.

To test for yourself, maybe try : Network Settings -> Adapter Options -> Configure -> Advanced.